# Chrome Dev Tools Protocol - Chrome kills websocket after 30 sec of inactivity

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am connecting to Chrome Dev Tools from my C#/.NET app via Chrome Dev Tools protocol running on WebSocket. I discovered that if no message in sent/received for 30 sec, chrome kills the connection and I get this WebSocketException :

```
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException:
The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.
```

Is there some way to dont let Chrome kill the connection ? Some elegant way to do keep-alive without manually sending blank messages every x seconds ?
I am using standard WebSocket from System.Net.WebSockets and connect like this:

```
var socket = new ClientWebSocket();
socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(target.webSocketDebuggerUrl),CancellationToken.None).Wait();
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried whatever socket/multiplexing/websocket framework you use send the PING message every 30 seconds? You show no relevant code / [mcve] so it's hard to suggest how you can best incorporate that into your code.

Comment: @Corion edited post with more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard .NET ClientWebSocket doesnt support manual pinging. However, it can be set via this property:

```
ClientWebSocket.ClientWebSocketOptions.KeepAliveInterval
```

The default value is 30 seconds, which is the same time after which the socket was getting closed. Setting this to some really high value made the problem dissapear. Unfortunately I am still not sure about the details of this problem and how does keep-alive work in .NET .